# c# Reference for DotNetZip

Tags: dotnetzip

I am using dotnetzip - I am using the following file as a reference -  Ionic.Zip.dll

I have it currently point to a location from my C: drive.
I usually use NuGet so not aware of how where I would put the .dll so that when it is promoted to Production, it runs from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on "References" folder/node in your Solution Explorer and choose "Add Reference". It will popup a dialog box which has the option for you to browse to the DLL file.

By default VS will copy the DLL to your project's output directory.